# Fancy box using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

Hi this is my java script code inside jsp. I want a success alert using fancy box after submit, how do I do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function translateData() {
    var word = $('#word').val();
    var lang = $('#lang').val();
    $("#result").html("loading...");
    $.post("translateAdmin.action", {
        word : word,lang:lang
    }, function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data);
    });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function translateData() {
    var word = $('#word').val();
    var lang = $('#lang').val();
    $("#result").html("loading...");
    $.post("translateAdmin.action", {
        word: word,
        lang: lang
    }, function (data) {
        $("#result").html(data);
        $.fancybox("success message"); // display alert after data is in #result
    });
}
```

**It's assumed** that you have properly included the fancybox js and css files

Comment: <s:textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="word" label="word" id="word"   value="%{#request.word1}">
  </s:textarea>
  <s:select label="Select Language" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Language" <input type="button" value="Translate" onclick="translateData()">
</div>
<div id="result" style="margin-top: 22px;">
Result:
<textarea rows="10" cols="50">
<s:iterator value="#request.mylist" status="translate">
<s:property value="trans"/></s:iterator>
</textarea>
</div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: this is my code, where do I include fancybox and css